# Maven doesn't package project with my jdk

Tags: java, maven

I built my jdk-11 (11.0.12) version from sources. I checked jdk on previous projects in Intellj, everything compiles and started without error,

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <encoding>${sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but when I used maven-compiler-plugin,and tried command: package war-file he told me

> Maven 3.3.1+ requires JDK 1.7+. Please set appropriate JDK

Other jdk (example corretto-11) working without problem.
What the problem?

My java -version (I built JDK myself)

```
openjdk version "11.0.12-internal" 2021-07-20 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fastdebug build 11.0.12-internal+0-adhoc.Eugene.jdk11u-c354f2ee0de8) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (fastdebug build 11.0.12-internal+0-adhoc.Eugene.jdk11u-c354f2ee0de8, mixed mode
```

Comment: the problem is you are building with an older version of the jdk, not with the one you think you're building with. Seeing as you are using Maven 3.3.1, it complains, stating that the jdk being used is older than 1.7, which is the minimum to use Maven 3.3.1, especially since you want it to compile as Java 11.

Comment: I built my jdk used openjdk-11. Problem show up, in IntelliJ IDEA when I used my JDK to Maven Runner

Comment: "I built my jdk", no you didn't. You installed one, no doubt, but it is clear that your maven is using an older jdk, not the latest one you have installed.

Comment: This it was bug in IntelliJ IDEA. They will be fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This it was bug in IntelliJ IDEA. They will be fix it in version 2021.2

Comment: You mean to say building from maven command line was warking all along, and only using IntelliJ had the issue?

Comment: I wrote at the top of the question about Intellij. Yes problem was only using IntelliJ. I wrote to Intellij support, and they replied that the problem will be fixed.

Comment: I'm seeing this in IntelliJ 2021.3.